# jackson deserialization into pojos

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize JSON Object coming from an application I can't control. Here my JSON :

```
{"assembly":
     {"name":"mm9",
      "id":32,
      "chromosomes":[
             {"chromosome":
                  {"name":"MT"}
             }]}}
```

My Pojos, are

```
class Assembly{
      private String name;
      private int id;
      private ArrayList<Chromosome> chromosomes;
      // getters & setters
}
class Chromosome {
     private String name;
     //getter/setters

}
```

But it's not working because of the extra fields "assembly" & "chromosome", so with a JSON like :

```
{"name":"mm9",
  "id":32,
    "chromosomes":[    
             {"name":"MT"}
                 ] }}
```

it simply working.
Is there a way to modify configuration or something to achieve this without create more complex POJOS?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the first JSON snippet, `chromosomes` is a dictionary (Map), of which one of the entries (`chromosome`) happens to correspond to your `Chromosome` object.

A more accurate direct mapping to a Java class would be

```
class Assembly{
  ...
  private Map<String, Chromosome> chromosomes;
}
```

Since you mention you can't control the format of the source JSON, you may want to look into using [custom deserializers](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers), or perhaps using the [streaming](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi) support from Jackson rather than ObjectMapper for direct mapping, if you aren't happy changing your POJOs in this way.

By the way, it is best to refer to collections by their interface type (`List`) rather than a concrete type (`ArrayList`). It is very unlikely that code that refers to this class truly cares or needs to know that it is using an `ArrayList`, referring to just the `List` interface instead makes it a lot easier to swap other implementations in if needed (as a general principle).

Comment: I did look at the deserializer and streaming support, and I will create my own parsing if I have no choice. I wanted simply something really fast to use because the keys (assembly,chromosome) are the name of the class. Something like : you see the word assembly, so use Assembly constructor. For the Map, it's really a list of chromosomes..